# Быстрое распознавание речи в python

Tags: python, распознавание-речи, pyttsx3

Сейчас я делаю голосового ассистента с помощью python и SpeechRecognition но каждый раз когда я говорю команду преображение этой команды в текст длится долго 
(5-15 сек.) и это очень не приятно.
Есть ли какой-то способ сделать процесс быстрее?
Ну или предложите другую библиотеку...

Вот код распознавания.

```
def recognize_cmd():
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    m = sr.Microphone(device_index=1)

    with m as source:
        print("---------")
        r.pause_threshold = 0.5
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        cmd = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-EN').lower()
        print("[log]User - " + cmd + '\n---------')
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        talk("Voice is not recognized!")
        cmd = recognize_cmd()

    return cmd
```

P.S.желательно чтобы в библиотеке была такая функция, какой является `adjust_for_ambient_noise()`
и, если можно предложите библиотеку которая будет работать offline

Comment: библиотека pocketsphinx она вроде оффлайн ,но я не работал с ней

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать [Vosk](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api)

Пример кода:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer
import os

if not os.path.exists("model-en"):
    print ("Please download the model from https://github.com/alphacep/kaldi-android-demo/releases and unpack as 'model' in the current folder.")
    exit (1)

import pyaudio

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=8000)
stream.start_stream()

model = Model("model-en")
rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, 16000)

while True:
    data = stream.read(2000)
    if len(data) == 0:
        break
    if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
        print(rec.Result())
    else:
        print(rec.PartialResult())

print(rec.FinalResult())
```

Другие примеры [тут](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/tree/master/python/example).

Устанавливается c помощью

```
pip install vosk
```

под Windows

```
pip install https://github.com/dtreskunov/tiny-kaldi/releases/download/0.3.1.2/vosk-0.3.1.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ обязательно попробую!

Comment: А это работает оффлайн?

Comment: да, работает без сети.

Comment: А можете отправить документацию, но на русском,

Comment: Но  всё нормально установилось, спасибо за ответ!