# DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3.7.7 64 Bit. Windows 10 64 Bit[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установил модуль `Vosk` при помощи `pip install https://github.com/dtreskunov/tiny-kaldi/releases/download/0.3.1.2/vosk-0.3.1.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`. Все установилось, но когда пытаюсь импортировать этот модуль выдает ошибку `from . import _vosk
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.`
Хотя в папке `site-packages` есть папка `vosk`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего vosk.pyd 32 разрядный или не хватает ещё одной длл, попробуй установить из pip из исходников

Там vosk.pyd от python 3.8, что не может слинковаться с другой версией Python.

Comment: `python37 -m pip install vosk`                                                                                                            
`Requirement already satisfied: vosk in c:\users\kazna\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (0.3.1.2)`

Comment: Вообще `vosk` вроде как не поддерживается для `Windows` если качать из PyPi. Но здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1087410/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%B2-python в ответе написано, что в этом репозитории https://github.com/dtreskunov/tiny-kaldi/releases/download/0.3.1.2/vosk-0.3.1.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl как раз таки под `Windows`

Comment: Возможно сборка кривая, удалить надо перед установкой